# In a EJB jar, where to put code to execute only once upon initialization?

Tags: java, initialization, ejb, listener

What I need: a place **inside EJB JAR** to put code which reads and caches configuration data from highly latent source (e.g. from DB with slow connection). Ideally, I'd like the **container** to guarantee this code to be executed only once.

**UPDATE:** we use EJB 3.0, so `@Singleton` is not an option. `@PostConstruct` methods have one shortcoming: they are executed once during bean lifecycle, so every time a bean is created, our slow code will be executed. Instead, I'd like to read the data only once during **application** startup and cache it.

To give some context: in Java Web applications, I get used to put my initilalization code into `SessionContextListener.contextInitialized()` method. 
As per Servlet spec [JSR 154](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/) (sections SRV.9.12, SRV.15.2.12.1), this method is called before any filter or servlet in the web application is initialized, and more important, called only once per given listener.

I realize I could place my code into that listener, but problem is that I need that conifguration data in my timer beans which started (presumably) before session context listener is fired. I could of course implement custom configuration factory, all slashed by `synchronized` blocks to handle caching and concurrent access. But manual synchronization always makes me sick.

Do you guys have any ideas on where to put this 'read config' code in EJB JAR? Or probably other approaches to reading and caching configuration data in multi-threaded environments?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a singleton EJB. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html.

You may choose to initialize it eagerly or lazily.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, we use EJB 3.0 where singleton beans are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can put code in a `static { }` block in any class and it will only get loaded **once per classloader**.

You can define a `Singleton` object with a `private` constructor and a `static` method that returns only a single instance of that class ever. This also falls in the **once per classloader** caveat.

Be aware that most, if not all J2EE/EJB containers use multiple classloaders so it will require lots of testing with your particular environment to guarantee that the code is run only once in whatever scope you have.

Comment: A **static** block can not reference non-static members. Its a restriction which should not be in terms of EJBs.

Comment: @Lion, I never said it should, nor does anything in my answer even hint at doing that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I lean to - the only downside I see is that exceptions thrown in static initializers lead to ExceptionInInitializerError and (AFAIR) subsequent NoClassDefFoundError which look ugly in catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Put a method under `@PostConstruct` in **EJB** as the one shown below.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    //Some EJB stuff.
}
```

---

The method `init()` will be executed only once when your **EJB** is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! But this method will be executed for each new bean instance - and I'd like to have something executed only once for all beans.